# Парсинг комментариев в XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Есть вот такой XML код, при парсинге обычным simplexml теряется вот это "`<user_data><!--[CDATA[https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=131823210&amp;token=z1ih7YeC]]--></user_data>`" что можно сделать?

```
<digiseller.response><retval>0</retval><retdesc></retdesc><id_seller>123321</id_seller><unique_code>321123</unique_code><inv>213213</inv><id_goods>1931072</id_goods><amount>1</amount><type_curr>WMR</type_curr><date_pay>08.05.2015 11:40:33</date_pay><email>superdooker@gmail.com</email><cnt_goods>1</cnt_goods><options><option id="6151"><name>Test</name><user_data><!--[CDATA[https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=131823210&amp;token=z1ih7YeC]]--></user_data></option><option id="6152"><name>����</name><user_data><!--[CDATA[https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=131823210&amp;token=z1ih7YeC]]--></user_data></option><option id="6153"><name>����2</name><user_data><!--[CDATA[https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=131823210&amp;token=z1ih7YeC]]--></user_data></option><option id="6154"><name>Test2</name><user_data><!--[CDATA[https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=131823210&amp;token=z1ih7YeC]]--></user_data></option></options></digiseller.response>
```

Comment: <!-- и --> попробуйте убрать

Comment: Для начала - правильно оформить CDATA (сейчас у вас это обычный комментарий)

Answer (score 2):

Правильно сформированная CDATA-секция должна выглядеть следующим образом

```
<![CDATA[https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=131823210&amp;token=z1ih7YeC]]>
```

у вас эта секция закомментирована

```
<!--[CDATA[https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=131823210&amp;token=z1ih7YeC]]-->
```

Можно извлечь из XML-файла и комментарии, однако simplexml не позволяет это сделать. Для решения задачи придется действовать через расширение xml и XPath

```
<?php
$xml = '<digiseller.response>...</digiseller.response>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$comments = $xpath->query('//options/option/user_data/comment()');
foreach($comments as $value) {
  echo substr(str_replace('[CDATA[', '', $value->data), 0, -2).'<br />';
}
```